# How do I fetch a Twitter account's email using Python and Tweepy?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth

How could I fetch the email for a Twitter account using Python and Tweepy?

I have the user authentication settings all set up and the "Request email from users" section on read. I am just wondering what the command/commands are to actually fetch the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GET account/verify_credentials](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials) with [`API.verify_credentials`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.8.0/api.html#tweepy.API.verify_credentials) to retrieve the email address of the user you're authenticated as.